# Dragging and dropping the img in a text editor does not fire mouseenter then

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery text editor and while editing I want to drag and drop images on the editor. But the problem is that after dropping img on jqte the `mouseenter` event does not fire.

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.jqte_editor img').on('mouseenter', function() { alert("hello"); 
           $(this).before("<div style='position:absolute'><input type='textbox'>
           </input></div>"); });
           });
```

the editor main container

```
       <div class="jqte_editor" contenteditable="true"><img ></img></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I misunderstood you! Disregard my previous answer.

When you use `on()` on the `.jqte_editor img` object, you're attaching the `mouseenter` event to all `<img>` elements within the `<div>`, and these events are attached **at the exact time that `on()` is called.** (This is called a *direct* event handler.) So, when you call it while the `<div>` is blank, there are no `<img>`s to attach the event to.

That's why, when you re-open the editor that has images already in it, your `on()` statement actually has images to attach the event to this time.

What you need is a *delegated* event handler. You would use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jqte_editor').on('mouseenter', 'img', function() {
        alert("hello"); 
        $(this).before("<div style='position:absolute'><input type='textbox'></input></div>");
    });
});
```

Basically, you attach the event to `.jqte_editor` itself. Then, you see that second argument in the `on()`? That selector means that this becomes a *delegated* event handler. It will trigger on any `<img>` within `.jqte_editor`, whether that image is already present or will be added dynamically in the future.

Comment: lol.. very few can answer and the rest only setting there to down vote. I hate down voters..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid, except for one issue: you're attaching the `mouseenter` handler to the selector `.jqte_editor img`. You have an `img` in your `jqte_editor` div, but since it has no `src` (nor does it have any CSS giving it width or height), it's an image of 0 width and 0 height. So, the `mouseenter` event can't trigger on that img because it isn't being rendered.

I used your code and attached the event to `.jqte_editor` instead, and it works as expected. [**Look at this fiddle to see it working.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2qEuT/1/)

Although, this event will fire whenever the mouse enters the div, even if the user isn't dragging anything. So, the following script detects when the content of the `div` is changed, and **only fires if an image has been added** ([**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2qEuT/2/)):

```
var contents = $('.jqte_editor').html();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jqte_editor').on("mouseenter", function() {
        if (contents != $(this).html()) {
            var to = contents.length;
            var diff = $(this).html().substr(length);
            if (diff.substr(0,4).toLowerCase() == "<img") {
                alert("Image added.");
                $(this).before("<div style='position:absolute'><input type='textbox'></input></div>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that is very nice. but what I posted was trimmed off. Actually when I drag the image and drop it. it is visible. but does not fire the mouseenter. When I store the edited text and reopen in the editor then it works ok. So my question is how to bind the mouseenter in this case.